# Understanding the scale of measurement of visceral fat (1 - 59)

Tags: weight-loss, body-fat, bellyfat, body-composition

I see that many-body composition measurement devices give visceral fat result as an integer between 1 and 59.  These are results I got from a body composition analysis.

- Weight: 87.7 kg
- Body fat: 19.9 %
- Subcutaneous fat: 17.2 %
- Visceral Fat: "9"

What does this number "9" mean?  By calculations, I was able to figure out that it is NOT:

- What percentage of total body weight is visceral fat.
- What percentage of body fat is visceral fat.
- How many kg visceral fat I have.

Is there a way to figure out:

- How much (kg) visceral fat should I lose to reduce this "9" to 4 or 3?
- How much (kg) visceral fat can I gain before the scale reaches 14?